# Is there a way to smooth scrolling in flot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I am currently using [this](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/navigate.html) chart from flot's examples page. I was just wondering if there is a way to make the zoom smoother or more lively. Is this supported in the latest version of flot or is there a good hack that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I had a similar problem with the resize plugin. I had flot graphs in a div that needed to grow/shrink with the browser window, and resizeing had the same choppiness. I found the resize plugin had a built-in 250ms delay for redrawing. I changed this to 0 and the result was perfectly smooth.

I'd look for something similar in the pan/zoom animation as it seems very similar.